Pound sign being replaced in bcp output
I really hope somebody can help me with this.
The database's collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and I can successfully output the pound sign with the following:
'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##Temp" queryout ' + @ExportPathFile + ' -C RAW -c -t, -T'
Output:

However, this only works when the output is a few lines. If the output is large and thousands of lines, then the £ is getting replaced:

The same happens if I try -C ACP and -C 1252 for the code page setting. Can anybody explain this and suggest a solution?

i'm guessing notepad++ ain't able to figure out the encoding so it mangles the pound. You should open file with proper encoding perhaps, or export as utf8 or unicode

0xA3 is Windows 1252 encode for £. I assume you're opening the file as a UTF-8 file in Notepad++, and 0xA3 isn't a represented character in that collation.

"this only works when the output is a few lines" conclusion: it is not a problem of bcp or sql-server please adapt the tags used.

Brilliant! Thank you @siggemannen and Thom A This is exactly what it is. I've tried to upvote you both but it looks like I did something wrong.
